# Array gets filled with strings instead of numbers on a conversion from jQuery to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Trying to convert a small snippet from jQuery to JS, I'm getting an array that contains strings instead of an array with numbers.

To be more exact, I'm getting this with script rewritten in JS:

[image: Array with strings]

The converted JS code looks like:

```
let pickEl = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass');
        // console.log(pickEl);
        pickEl.forEach(pickEl => {
            let r = new RegExp('(' + term + ')', "ig");

            if(pickEl.textContent.match(r)) {
                // console.log(pickEl.innerHTML.match(r));
                let matches = pickEl.textContent.match(r);

                matches.forEach(function(i) {
                    occurrences.push(i);
                });
                // wrap each found term in span with class found to highlight it
                pickEl.innerHTML.replace(r, '<span class="found">$&</span>');
                console.log(pickEl.textContent.replace(r, '<span class="found">$&</span>'));
            }
        });
```

Instead of this in jQuery:

[image: Array with numbers(indexes)]

The jQuery code looks like:

```
$('.some').each(function (i) {
            var r = new RegExp('(' + term + ')', "ig");

            if ($(this).html().match(r)) {
                var matches = $(this).html().match(r);
                console.log(matches);
                console.log('Var matches =' + ' ' + matches);
                $.each(matches, function () {
                    occurences.push(i);
                });
                // wrap each found search term with our `found` span to highlight it 
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace(r, '<span class="found">$1</span>'));
            }
        });
```

How should I write the JS code in order to obtain the same array as in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of what `i` actually is in your two codes: in the native JS version, `i` refers to the entries returned by [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), while `i` in your jQuery version comes from the [first argument of the `.each` method](https://api.jquery.com/each/), which is the index.

If you want to access the index, then you need to get it from the outer forEach function applied to `pickEl`. Refer to the comments with `// NOTE:`, where I have added my annotations:

```
let pickEl = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass');
    // NOTE: Access the index of the current element
    pickEl.forEach((pickEl, index) => {
        let r = new RegExp('(' + term + ')', "ig");

        if(pickEl.textContent.match(r)) {
            // console.log(pickEl.innerHTML.match(r));
            let matches = pickEl.textContent.match(r);

            matches.forEach(function() {
                // NOTE: Push the index into array
                occurrences.push(index);
            });
            // wrap each found term in span with class found to highlight it
            pickEl.innerHTML.replace(r, '<span class="found">$&</span>');
            console.log(pickEl.textContent.replace(r, '<span class="found">$&</span>'));
        }
    });
```